# How can I vertically center 1 div and have another div at the bottom (Without using position absolute)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

So I have a container div that has a height of 500px and a width of 500px.

Now, I have 2 divs that I want to insert into that container div. Let's name the 'A' and 'B'.

I want 'A' to be vertically centered and I want 'B' to be at the bottom of the container div.

I'll draw it out:

[image]

My solution was to use flex box and justify-content-between and to use 3 divs. The first div would be an empty div, and div 'A' and div 'B' would just follow.

I don't like the idea of using an empty div **and I don't want to use position absolute**, so if anyone could please help me find another solution, that would be great!

[image]

Comment: Hello, I made a quick example for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5skrd7v/8/) using flexbox. Hope it helps you! :)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli Your A and B are not centered horizontally (they are offset just a little)

Comment: Thanks @dgrogan, I just noticed the issue and the little offset. An easy fix would be to add `transform: translateX(-100%)` to the second div `.b` which would center them under each other perfectly. I updated the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rhgwnmuL/56/)

Answer (score -2):

If they are both within a parent div, you could use absolute positioning to set a top of 50%, display: flex, flex-direction: column and then justify content space between all on the parent.